# Flutter Riverpod ref.read() vs ref.listen() vs ref.watch()

Tags: flutter, dart, riverpod

After reading the [documentation](https://riverpod.dev/docs/concepts/reading), it did not explain very well what `ref.read()`, `ref.watch()`, and `ref.listen()` is.

The questions I have are as follows:

- What is the purpose and difference between these functions?
- Where and where not can I use these functions?
- When should I use these functions?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

### What is the purpose and difference between these functions?

#### read()

Use `read` to the get the value of/in provider just once (one-time read)

#### watch()

Use `watch` to the get the value of/in provider the first time and every time the value changes (see it like you're subscribing to the provider, so you get notified any time there's a change)

### listen()

`listen` is similar to `watch`. The main difference is the return type.
`watch` returns the new value directly, `listen` returns a `void` but gives access to the new value and the old value with a callback (See examples below)

### Where and where not can I use these functions?

You can use `read` in places like `initState` , callbacks like `onPressed` etc. `watch` and `listen` should not be called asynchronously, like inside an `onPressed` of an ElevatedButton. Nor should it be used inside `initState` and other State life-cycles.

As Kaan Taha Köken pointed out:

> **AVOID** using [read] for creating widgets with a value that never changes and **CONSIDER** using [Provider] or `select` for filtering unwanted rebuilds.

### When should I use these functions?

#### read()

Use `read` when you want to value of the provider only once.

#### watch()

Use `watch` when you want to always get the value.

### Example: Counter app with `StateProvider`

```
final counterProvider = StateProvider((ref) => 0);
class HomePage extends ConsumerWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    final counter = ref.watch(counterProvider);
    ref.listen(
      counterProvider,
      (previous, next) {
        print("The new value is $next");
        if (next == 5) {
          print("I just reached 5");
        }
      },
    );
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Text(
          counter.toString(),
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          ref.read(counterProvider.state).state += 1;
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The example above shows the use of `watch`, `read` and `listen`.

- We're `watch`ing the `counter` value so it gets updated in the UI anytime there is a change.
- We're `listen`ing to the `counter` to print the updated value and print `I've reached 5` when it is 5.
- To increment the value, we `read` the provider state and add `1` when the `FloatingActionButton` is pressed.

Comment: it is not advised to use `read` inside build method. It is already mentioned in the docs. Also, for the sake of counter-example, instead of using `ref.read`, it is suggesting different approach.

Comment: https://riverpod.dev/docs/concepts/reading checkout the lower section of this page

Comment: @KaanTahaKöken, `ref.read` can be called anywhere, while it's not advised - If you have a particular use case (say you only want to read an object just once and you don't want it to get updated) then using it is very fine.

Comment: For the counter example in the documentation, the example was written using a `StateNotifierProvider` but it doesn't mean writing the counter app with `StateProvider` is wrong - In fact, using `StateProvider` for a simple `Counter` app (as seen in the example) is more advisable.

Comment: If you hover over `ref.read` it gives the exact use case. Using `ref.read` especially inside `ConsumerWidget's` build gave me a lot of headaches. The only use case that I prefer using on onTap/onPressed. Generally, prefer using watch with select

Comment: I guess you're right, I've updated my answer.